# accounting for returned items in sales data

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I am working with medicine sales data and counting the dates on which patients have consumed the medicine.
Patients can be on multiple medicines and I would have to count the number of days each medicine was consumed (irrespective of the number of times consumed per day, I would still count it as one day of therapy)
Scenario 1: Overall net of the sales and returned quantities is 0, this patient will get excluded. As he/she did not consume any medicine.
Scenario 2: A patient has received medicine for 3 days, bought medicines for day 4 but was advised to stop, and returned on the same day. So net of the sales and returned quantities on day 4 will be O. This patient will be considered to have consumed medicine for 3 days.
Scenario 3: Same as scenario 2, but the patient returns the medicine on day 5 or day 6.

I need help in addressing the scenario 3 and removing the date 4 when the drug was brought but not consumed. Note: quantities might sometimes be different (brought 10 and returned 8 - this needs to included whereas when quantities of purchase and returned both match, only then it should be removed.

Used this for scenario 2:

```
grp_consump_use = net_consump_use.groupby(['trandate', 'unique_id ', 'medicine'])['qty'].sum().reset_index()

grp_consump_use['pos_sale'] =  grp_consump_use['qty']>=1

consump_use = grp_consump_use[grp_consump_use['pos_sale']]

consump_use = consump_use.drop(columns = ['pos_sale'])
```

Example:

```
| trandate   | medicine |unique_id | quantity|
| ---------- | -------- |--------- | ------- |
| 2023/03/10 | a        |12345     |  2      |
| 2023/03/10 | b        |12345     |  1      |
| 2023/03/11 | a        |12345     |  2      |
| 2023/03/11 | b        |12345     |  1      |
| 2023/03/12 | a        |12345     |  2      |
| 2023/03/12 | b        |12345     |  1      |
| 2023/03/13 | a        |12345     |  2      |
| 2023/03/13 | b        |12345     |  2      |
| 2023/03/14 | a        |12345     |  -2     |
| 2023/03/14 | b        |12345     |  2      |
```

Expected result:

```
| medicine |unique_id | days |
| -------- | -------- | ---- |
| a        |12345     |  3   |
| b        |12345     |  5   |
```